# Select record by Primary Key

Tags: javascript, json

I have some JSON data where I define presets with a unique identifier `ID`, (you could call it a primary key). Besides `ID` there are a bunch of other properties defined, including `somethingelse`. I want to extract the `somethingelse` property of a particular record, identified by its ID. I tried this:

```
function getSomethingElse(id) {
    return presets[id].somethingelse; 
}
```

But obviously the above code will only access the preset with array position `id`. I'm trying to access the preset where the actual ID is `id`.

This might be a dumb question, but I haven't been able to find any example of what I'm trying to do!

Comment: If your preset was a hashmap/object then the ID could be used with the same syntax to access the item.

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying the array/object misunderstanding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If ID is used as a primary key then I'd suggest converting your preset data to a hashmap instead of an an array.

```
var presets= {};
presets["guid1"] = "hello"
presets["guid2"] = "world"
```

This should work exactly as your posted code intends.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `$scope.presets` is an array, You need to iterate your objects like

```
$scope.loadPreset(id) {
    angular.forEach($scope.presets, function(value, key) {
        if(value.id == id){
            $scope.somethingelse = value.somethingelse; 
        }         
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer is obviously correct but in this case @mccainz was more helpful, since it clarified the array/object misunderstanding.